# Setting Hyper-V snapshot's name programmatically

Tags: c#, wmi, snapshot, hyper-v

I'm creating an Hyper-V snapshot with a C# program:

```
    private static bool Snapshot(string vmName, string snapshotName)
    {
        var result = false;
        var scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\virtualization", null);
        var virtualSystemService = Utility.GetServiceObject(scope, "Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService");

        var vm = Utility.GetTargetComputer(vmName, scope);

        var inParams = virtualSystemService.GetMethodParameters("CreateVirtualSystemSnapshot");
        inParams["SourceSystem"] = vm.Path.Path;

        var outParams = virtualSystemService.InvokeMethod("CreateVirtualSystemSnapshot", inParams, null);

        if ((UInt32)outParams["ReturnValue"] == ReturnCode.Started)
        {
            if (Utility.JobCompleted(outParams, scope))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Snapshot was created successfully.");
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to create snapshot VM");
                result = false;
            }
        }
        else if ((UInt32)outParams["ReturnValue"] == ReturnCode.Completed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Snapshot was created successfully.");
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Create virtual system snapshot failed with error {0}", outParams["ReturnValue"]);
            result = false;
        }

        inParams.Dispose();
        outParams.Dispose();
        vm.Dispose();
        virtualSystemService.Dispose();

        return result;
    }
```

(NOTE: This code was taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136785%28v=VS.85%29.aspx))

Is there a way to set the snapshot name through this WMI call ? Otherwise, does anyone know a working solution to rename a snapshot through WMI call? I already found [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/servervirtualization/thread/13f4f411-277c-4a8c-989a-55916471b865), but it's some kind of ambiguous and it doesn't provide any solution ...

EDIT: The solution was to rename snapshot after having create it. Here's my function to rename the snapshot using Hans advice:

SOLUTION:

```
    public static bool RenameSnapshot(string vmName, string snapshotName)
    {

        var result = false;
        var scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\virtualization", null);
        var vm = Utility.GetTargetComputer(vmName, scope);

        // load snapshot
        var objSnapshot = GetLastVirtualSystemSnapshot(vm);

        // rename snapshot
        objSnapshot["ElementName"] = snapshotName;

        // save
        var virtualSystemService = Utility.GetServiceObject(scope, "Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService");
        var inParams = virtualSystemService.GetMethodParameters("ModifyVirtualSystem");
        inParams["ComputerSystem"] = vm.Path.Path;
        inParams["SystemSettingData"] = objSnapshot.GetText(TextFormat.CimDtd20);
        var outParams = virtualSystemService.InvokeMethod("ModifyVirtualSystem", inParams, null);

        if ((UInt32)outParams["ReturnValue"] == ReturnCode.Completed)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }



        inParams.Dispose();
        outParams.Dispose();
        vm.Dispose();
        virtualSystemService.Dispose();


        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `ModifyVirtualSystem` method of the `Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService` class to rename a hyper-v snapshot. There is a [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136809%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) example on how to rename a hyper-v virtual machine (You have to modify the code in order to rename a snapshot). Furthermore I've found this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/Web/dotpanel/dotPanel/Providers/Virtualization/HyperV.cs.htm) on how to rename a hyper-v snapshot.
Hope, this helps.